# month vs month query (data in the same table)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, subquery

I have the access table with the structure as bellow.
[image]

I want to do a query that will substract the VOLUME from last month (the month of the data in in SOURCE field) from the data that was inputed this month.

For the example above the result should be something like:

```
SOURCE | VERSION | SALES MODEL | DESTINATION | PERIOD | VOLUME |
-------+---------+-------------+-------------+--------+--------|
201309 |   1     |   model 1   |     eu      | 201309 |    -1  |
```

In the table I have more models, more months and more sources. I need to have the source and source-1 substraction all the time and the data should match to the model, destination and period.
So if I have 3 sources (instead of two as above) it should return the 201308-201307 and 201309-201308 results.
Is this possible in access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join a table onto itself by using table aliases. Once you know this the only tricky thing is figuring out what month value comes immediately after another.

```
Select
  t1.source,
  t1.version,
  t1.[sales model],
  t1.destination,
  t1.period,
  t1.volume - t2.volume as volume
From
  table t1
    inner join
  table t2
    on
      t1.Source = IIf(t2.source Mod 100 = 12, t2.Source + 89, t2.Source + 1) And
      t1.version = t2.version and
      t1.[sales model] = t2.[sales model] and
      t1.destination = t2.destination and
      t1.period = t2.period
```

Edit - fixed the next month test for December